# Bug in python/multiprocessing.pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

(this is using Python 2.7)

I have found similar links but not about the exact same issue than what I am having.
This program hangs on the map_async, and never finishes, I can see the Python process getting created but it never completes:

```
import multiprocessing


def main():
    PROCESSES = 4
    print 'Creating pool with %d processes\n' % PROCESSES
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(PROCESSES)
    r = pool.map_async(pow3, range(10))
    r.wait()


def pow3(x):
    try:
        return x**3
    except:
        print('%s: %s' % (x, traceback.format_exc()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine.
Are you running this in an interactive interpreter?
See this note from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html):

> Note Functionality within this package requires that the **main**
>    module be importable by the children. This is covered in Programming
>    guidelines however it is worth pointing out here. This means that some
>    examples, such as the multiprocessing.Pool examples will not work in
>    the interactive interpreter. For example:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pool   
>>> p = Pool(5)   

>>> def f(x):   
...     return x*x  

>>> p.map(f, [1,2,3])
```

Process PoolWorker-1:
 Process PoolWorker-2:
 Process PoolWorker-3:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'f'

(If you try this it will actually output three full tracebacks interleaved in a semi-random fashion, and then you may have to stop the master process somehow.)

Comment: I am trying this in pyScripter, it was working fine until Friday. You seem to be right, it works when I just run the program by double clicking it (running through python.exe)